# How to use runSession from: Test.WebDriver in haskell selenium webdriver?

Tags: haskell, selenium, webdriver, monads

I'm new in Haskell (although I'm after reading LYAH).
I have no idea what should I do to use selenium webdriver ([webdriver link on hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/webdriver)).
I'm pretty sure that I should run one of these functions

```
runWD :: WDSession -> WD a -> IO aSource
runSession :: WDSession -> Capabilities -> WD a -> IO aSource
withSession :: WDSession -> WD a -> WD aSource
```

but i don't understand how to get this WD structure which is define as:

```
WD (StateT WDSession IO a)   
Instances:
Monad WD     
Functor WD   
Applicative WD   
MonadCatchIO WD  
MonadIO WD   
WebDriver WD     
SessionState WD  
MonadBase IO WD  
MonadBaseControl IO WD
```

I wonder also what is the purpose of this WD structure?

Code example or indication of what I should have read about Haskell to understand what is going on here will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference page says that `WD` is

> A monadic interface to the WebDriver server. This monad is a simple,
>   strict layer over IO, threading session information between sequential
>   commands

So you can do something like this:

```
foo = runWD defaultSession $ do
    liftIO $ putStrLn "Hello WD"
    somethingElse
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was very helpful.
Here is the code snippet which prints the title of stack overflow:
`import Test.WebDriver

main = runSession defaultSession defaultCaps $ do
 openPage "http://stackoverflow.com"
 getTitle`

I still don't fully understand what does it mean "layer" but i will leave it until tomorow ;)